# Youtube API Send Video Message

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am using [youtube API for messages](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_messages.html) to send a youtube message. It works only when I am sending video message and add video id in the request body. I can't send a message without a video. Is there any other API method to send without the video?

Also, I can't set message title. Isn't it supported?

Also, is there a method to send a message reply?

Comment: please give me the send message script. i got so many error. so please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There is currently no way to send a message without a video.
- It is not possible to reply to a message.